# Concurrency - why does the last instruction in this function never execute?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have this code:

```
private void doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
    WorkerThread w= new WorkerThread(this);
    w.start();
    synchronized (synchObj) {
        while (!isDone) {
            synchObj.wait();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("End");
}
```

Where the calling class implements a method that calls `notifyAll()` on `synchObj` when `WorkerThread` instance is done. Everything works pretty much as expected except the final call to `System.out.println("End");` is never called. Why is that?

**Edit:** Here's the rest of the code:

```
public class App implements Notifee {
    private boolean isDone = false;
    private final Object synchObj = new Object();
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                app.doSomething();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("Didn't even start");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }       

    private void doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
        WorkerThread w= new WorkerThread(this);
        w.start();
        synchronized (synchObj) {
            while (!isDone) {
                synchObj.wait();
            }
        }
            System.out.println("End");
    }

    @Override
    public void letMeKnow() {
        synchronized (synchObj) {
            synchObj.notifyAll();
        }
    }       
}

public class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    private Notifee n;
    public WorkerThread(Notifee n){
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        n.letMeKnow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever change the value of `isDone` ?

Comment: Do you call synchObj.notify() from anywhere?

Comment: It is only possible not to execute the last line when it actually throws InterruptedException.

Comment: Does your program terminate correctly? I suspect you might have a deadlock on your synchronized statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never setting `isDone` to `true`. Also you should make it `volatile`. You probably should add:

```
@Override
public void letMeKnow() {
    isDone = true;
    synchronized (synchObj) {
        synchObj.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

**Edit**: If you want to just wait for the worker thread to finish call:

```
w.join();
```

Comment: The reason for the `while()` is that there could be a spurious wake from the `wait()`, so looping mitigates that risk.

Comment: Why `volatile`? Spurious wakeups make the `while` loop necessary. It's generally considered a very poor idea to use `if` in these circumstances anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid oversight. What I wanted was for the main thread to wait until WorkerThread completed. Which it's not doing, obviously. Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I removed the if suggestion. @Johnny: Just call w.join() instead.

Comment: I would move `isDone = true;` inside the synchronized block.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: volatile is necessary if you are modifying a variable in one thread and reading it in another one. If it gets cached in the core of the reader thread you will deadlock.

Comment: @Tudor The `synchronized` blocks take care of that. Just as well!

Comment: I know that locks introduce fences, but in general I think it's a good practice if you do cross-thread read/writes. Other readers of your code can then deduce that this variable is used for special signaling purposes.